# FreeTDS and nvarchar(max) data

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I use a php application for managing a Microsoft SQL Server Database. The application is installed to unix and uses FreeTDS. While I do not have any problem to read / write data for nvarchar(n), I cannot handle correctly nvarchar(max) data for UTF-8.

Configuration file for freetds:

```
    host = x
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
    client charset = UTF-8
```

Is there any other option for freetds in order to handle correclty nvarchar(max) data?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual error message? Suggest editing your question to include this. Which version of freetds?

Comment: does it handle varchar(max)? does FreeTDS documentation even address "max" length strings?  it just may not support that.

Answer (score 2):

You need TDS 7.2, which adds support for SQL Server 2005 and MAX types, see [Choosing a TDS protocol version](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm):

> TDS: 7.2  Includes support for varchar(max), varbinary(max), xml datatypes and MARS[a].

Comment: I tried tds version = 7.2 with no luck (using version 0.82 of freetds). Another problem has to do with freetds logging, so I cannot report any error log. Anyway, I am wondering if anybody else had the same problem.

Comment: Can you give some more specific detail what does it mean `cannot handle correctly nvarchar(max) data for UTF-8`?

Comment: Yes. For example when trying to add some greek text, i.e. INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (N'αβγ'), the application stores garbage characters to the database (aß?).

Comment: Problem solved. There was a bug to my code while reading the data. Thanks for your time!